# using Playerprefs on Android Mobile Platform for unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I have a question about playerprefs on my android mobile game not initializing properly. I have already pre-set my playerprefs data on a variable with a value of 3. In my play mode on unity the value is showing 3 through the textmesh that I have it scripted on. But when I install and test it on my android mobile device it is 0. can someone help how to properly initialize my playerprefs data to the right value on android platform?

```
public static Game GM;
int maxAntiBody;
public TextMeshProUGUI antibodyTexMesh;

void Start () {
if (GM == null)
{
    GM = this;
}
maxAntiBody = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MaxAntiBody");
antibodyTexMesh.text = maxAntibody.toString();
}

void Update () {
 debugging();
}

 //I use this method for setting or resetting my desired value for the 
playerprefs data I'm working with. In this case I choose 3 as a value.

void debugging() {
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.M))
{

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MaxAntiBody", plus++);
    Debug.Log("max anti body value is : " + 
 PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MaxAntiBody"));
}
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
{
    plus = 0;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MaxAntiBody", plus);
    Debug.Log("max anti body is now reseted to : " + 
  PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MaxAntiBody"));
}
}
```

Comment: Quick reminder; playerprefs are stored on the device - so changes you make in the editor on windows are stored to some folder on disk. You android device won't have that file - so the changes are unique per environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only ever setting the playerpreference when you press the M or R key (in your debugging method).

if you want the value to have a default value you should add it to your `Start();`

Something like;

```
void Start()
{

    // Set the MAxAntiBody to 3 if the value was never set to an initial value
    if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MaxAntiBody") == default(int))        
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MaxAntiBody", 3);

    ...

}
```

EDIT: as pointed out in the comments you could also do the following:

```
var x = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MaxAntiBody", 3);
```

> Returns the value corresponding to key in the preference file if it exists. If it doesn't exist, it will return defaultValue.

Do not that the first piece of code actually creates the key if `GetInt()` returns the default value (0) - but the second sample may not. This depends on the implementation of `GetInt(string, int)` - and i'm not sure if that creates the key if it does not exist.

Comment: Sorry. It's my fault. But why not `PlayerPrefs.GetInt( key , default_value );` instead?

Comment: `default(int)` is just long way of writing `0` i.e. doesn't guarantee that this value wasn't set before

Comment: @AndrewŁukasik well thanks anyways for trying to clear this up! :). Whether you use `default(int)` or `0` is just a bit of flavor. I don't think its harmfull to use either approach. I personally used `default(int)` in this particular case, because i want the reader to know that i'm comparing against the default value rather than a value (0). It adds some readability, i instantly understand i'm comparing at the default value so i know faster what i'm doing here. As for `PlayerPrefs.GetInt(string, int)` i did not know it existed. I personally don't think both warrant a downvote btw.